# Filter ZoneId by country code using java.time

Tags: java, time, timezone, java-time

I get a list of all of the available zoneId's as shown below using `java.time`:

```
Set<String> zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
```

I want to filter these zone id values using country codes e.g. "GB", "DE", "FR" as shown below:

Note: In this example I just tried to get one timeZone for France:

```
final List<String> timeZones = Stream.of(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds())
            .filter(zoneId -> zoneId.startsWith("FR")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it throws "Cannot resolve method 'startsWith' in 'Set'". So, how can filter time zones using country codes?

Comment: Maybe try `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()` instead of `Stream.of(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds())`. Your code will produce a stream of Sets.

Comment: You could use `startsWith` on a `String` representation, use `zoneId -> zoneId.toString().startsWith("FR")` but I really doubt you will get any results.

Comment: There are no country codes on the time zones identifier. **There is no `FR`, `GB`, or `DE` for you to filer.**  [See the list](https://ideone.com/q6bkQy): `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().forEach( System.out::println )`. And you have [already asked this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67813095/642706).

Comment: So, what is the **solution** in this scene?

Comment: @BasilBourque But there is not any solution for neither of them. Any idea?

Comment: @deHaar Thanks but not working.

Comment: @csalmhof What is changed? Does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: @Maxwell. Take a look at the Java documentation and what `Stream.of(T t)` does: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T)

Comment: If there was a strong connection between `Locale` and `ZoneId`, one could filter the `Locale`s by country code and then determine (possible) connected `ZoneId`s, but there is no connection as far as I know...

Comment: What about using some external libraries? I think there is no other way?